# Converting a string to an integer failing in Azure Data Factory pipeline

Tags: type-conversion, azure-data-factory, pipeline, sqldatatypes

I have constructed an ADF pipeline with copy data to create a CSV from an Azure SQL DB query. It needs to run as a delta load each time, so I have the following...

**Lookup** - To get the maximum row ID of the last run, which is stored in a table in the database

**Set Variable** - To assign that value to a variable (which is a string as ADF doesn't have an int var)

**Copy Data** - Runs the query and generates the CSV file in a storage blob

**Lookup** - To get the maximum row ID of the table I'm pulling the data from

**Set Variable** - To update the variable value from the ID of the last run to the max ID of this run

**Script** - An update statement to write the max ID back to the DB ready for the next run

It all works up until the update statement, where it fails when trying to convert the ID variable to an integer. (Statement modified slightly for public view)

```
UPDATE
    [dbo].[DeltaLoads]
SET
    [MaxId] = 'int(@{variables('MaxRowId')})'
WHERE
    [Client] = '<ClientName>'
    AND [RuntimeVariable] = 'MaxRowId'
```

As the value is numeric and only ever will be numeric, why does the conversion from the string fail? Have I written the expression incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your expression like below and I got same error.

```
Update [dbo].[sample1] set [MaxId]='int(@{variables('MaxRowId')})' where name='Laddu';
```

[image]

Here, your expression will result the query like below in the script activity input.

```
Update [dbo].[sample1] set [MaxId]='int(24)' where name='Laddu';
```

where `'int(24)'` is a varchar value and it is the cause of the error.

To resolve this, modify your query like below. convert the string to integer in ADF expression using `@{int(variables('MaxRowId'))}` like below.

```
Update [dbo].[sample1] set [MaxId]=@{int(variables('MaxRowId'))} where name='Laddu';
```

This will give the query like below which you can see in the script activity input.

[image]

And you can see my row also updated in the table.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I get a different error now when using that expression... An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
Incorrect syntax near ''.

Comment: The input for the update script is the below and the initial run returns a 0 as expected (as there is no data in the dev source table) but it should still execute the update statement.
    "scripts": [
        {
            "type": "Query",
            "text": "UPDATE\n    [dbo].[<Removed>]\nSET\n    [MaxId] = {\"\":0}\nWHERE\n    [Client] = '<Removed>'\n    AND [RuntimeVariable] = 'MaxId'\n    AND [RunInterval] = 'Daily'"
        }
    ],
    "scriptBlockExecutionTimeout": "02:00:00",
    "logSettings": {
        "logDestination": "ActivityOutput"
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue. ADF will actually pass the 'int' function as part of the code to Azure SQL which doesn't recognize it.
Please use the following code instead:

```
UPDATE
    [dbo].[DeltaLoads]
SET
    [MaxId] = @{variables('MaxRowId')}
WHERE
    [Client] = 'client_name'
    AND [RuntimeVariable] = 'MaxRowId'
```

The Actual code that will run against SQL server will be this:

```
UPDATE
    [dbo].[DeltaLoads]
SET
    [MaxId] = 18
WHERE
    [Client] = 'client_name'
    AND [RuntimeVariable] = 'MaxRowId'
```

Which doesn't need conversion, since the number (18) does not have apostrophe ('') that recognize it as a string

Comment: Maybe it's due to the preceding task but the input to the update is [MaxId] = {\"\":0}, so it is returning the integer, which is 0 in this case, however, it still appears to be treating it as a string.